# Paypal login via Curl (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, paypal

There is a problem when I try to login to Paypal via Curl, I think I have all post fields correctly setup, but it doesn't give any output. I want to receive the page content after login, but there is no actual output.

Code:

```
    $loginUrl = 'https://www.paypal.com/en/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-submit&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8d66f31424b43e9a70645c907a6cbd8fb4';

    //init curl
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(

        'User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0',
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-language: nl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
        'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'login_email='.urlencode($username).'&login_password='.urlencode($password).'&submit=inloggen&browser_name=Firefox&browser_version=32&browser_version_full=32.0&operating_system=Windows&bp_mid='.urlencode('v=1;a1=na~a2=na~a3=na~a4=Mozilla~a5=Netscape~a6=5.0 (Windows)~a7=20100101~a8=na~a9=true~a10=Windows NT 6.3; WOW64~a11=true~a12=Win32~a13=na~a14=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0~a15=false~a16=nl~a17=na~a18=www.paypal.com~a19=na~a20=na~a21=na~a22=na~a23=1600~a24=900~a25=24~a26=860~a27=na~a28=Wed Oct 29 2014 17:56:23 GMT+0100~a29=1~a30=na~a31=yes~a32=na~a33=na~a34=no~a35=no~a36=yes~a37=no~a38=online~a39=no~a40=Windows NT 6.3; WOW64~a41=no~a42=no~&').'bpks1='.  urlencode('v=1;l=8;Di0:141497Ui0:99Di1:182').'&bpks2=&bpks3=');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    exit(var_dump($content)); // OUTPUT: string(26) ▒▒";
```

I have tried this on other websites successfully, so I have no idea why this isn't working? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You do realize PayPal uses an intermediate page to prevent what you're doing, right?

Comment: Actually not, does that mean there is no solution at all?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
//Header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.paypal.com/pl/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-submit&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8de62a88b92df045c56447d40d60b23a7c");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return server response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: 127.0.0.1", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: 127.0.0.1")); 


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookieJar.txt'); // save cookie file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.paypal.com');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // use post data

$post = array(
    "login_cmd" => null,
    "login_params" => null,
    "login_email" => "test",
    "login_password" => "test",
    "submit.x" => "login",
    //"auth" => "AOeCYVv0IxkugC2Pyz2AhTaW2P7hWuy5w9FoeuyB48gjjJZN3mTtuL79Tzs9dY.CF",
    "form_charset" => "UTF-8",
    "browser_name" => "Chrome",
    "browser_version" => "537.36",
    //"browser_version_full" => "40.0.2214.115",
    //"operating_system" => "Windows",
);

$post = http_build_query($post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

print_r($data);


?>
```